# Dynamic Links in that auto navigates to the top of a div

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, hyperlink

I have a forum whereby links to a thread looks like

`http://www.website.com/comments.php?topic_id=1`

How can I make it look like this

`http://www.website.com/1046302/some-link-desc#12154109`

so that when such links are given out, the user is taken directly to that particular comment.

I'm particular about the `#12154109` . The other part of the URL `/1046302/some-link-desc` is achieved through .htaccess configuration.

**Question Update**

What is the best way to get the unique number ? Do I use a timestamp or a concatenation of the topic_id and comment_id ?

Comment: This is what the `<a>` anchor html element does.  It is an anchor to a part of the page...

Comment: `<a name="12154109"></a>` and `<a href="#12154109">comment</a>`

Comment: How do you retrieve that 12154109? (looks like an unique timestamp)

Comment: `<a name="12154109">` would then take you to that comment ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to apply a the following tag in the comment portion of your template.

```
<a name"1215409"></a>
```

of course the number would be set to the comment id.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to do this through htaccess. The [*fragment*, the `#something` part of the URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), tells the client specifics on how to handle the content that it was served, in the case of anchors, it tells the browser where to seek to in the page. The fragment is never sent to the server, so apache never sees it, and thus nothing in the htaccess file can match against it or use it in any way.

Fragments are also used by javascript which can look at the URL to pull stuff out of the fragment or to force a script to rerun by reloading the page with a different fragment.

You can, however, send fragments to the client from the server, but there's no way to know whether the client already has the fragment or not. But the content itself will need to have the fragments in the links, htaccess isn't going to know which anchors are in the actual content that ends up being served.